# Error Uncaught ArgumentCountError i cant find it

Tags: php

I added more variables to the default function of wordpress and I see this error.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

```
add_action('new_to_pending', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email');
 add_action('draft_to_pending', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email');
 add_action('auto-draft_to_pending', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email');
add_action('init', 'approve_post');

function set_html_content_type() { return 'text/html'; }


add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 5 );


  function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( 
 $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname, $post ) {

    // get author of post
$author = new WP_User($post->post_author);
 // create a key for security check and save as meta
$check = md5( $author->user_email . $post->ID  );
update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_approve_key', $check);
   // set the content for the email

    // create an url vor verify link with some variables: key, post id, and email
   $url = add_query_arg( 
   array(
  'email'=>$author->user_email,
  'approve'=>$post->ID),
  site_url()
  );

  $check = md5( $author->user_email . $post->ID  );
   update_post_meta( $post->ID, '_approve_key', $check);
  $key = get_password_reset_key( $user );

 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
 $message = sprintf(__('Bienvenido,')) . "\r\n\r\n";
 $message = "Tu cuenta:
  " . sprintf(__('%s'), $user->user_email) . "
   <br>
  Para establecer la contraseña:
   " . "\r\n\r\n";


  $enlace1= "". network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n" . "";

 $message .='<a href= "' . $url . '" onclick="window.open("' . $enlace1 . '" , \'_blank\', \'width=600,height=350\');" >Crear Contraseña</a>'. "\r\n";

$message .= "Saludos," . "\r\n";

 $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;

return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Error

Error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email(), 3 passed in ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how you're using the `wp_new_user_notification_email` filter. As  you'll see from [its documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_new_user_notification_email/), the callback function receives 3 arguments:

- `$wp_new_user_notification_email`
- `$user`
- `$blogname`

However, the function you're using as the callback accepts 4 arguments.

```
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( 
 $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname, $post ) {
```

Plus you've set the number of arguments to be passed to the callback to `5`:

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 5 );
```

Your callback function needs to accept at least the same number of arguments passed you specify in the `add_filter()` call, and that number can't be any more than passed by the original filter.

So update your `add_filter()` call to support all `3` arguments:

```
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 10, 3 );
```

And then make sure `custom_wp_new_user_notification_email()` function only accepts those arguments:

```
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( 
 $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
```

You're also going to need to address your usage of `$post` in the `custom_wp_new_user_notification_email()` function. As I've shown,  the `wp_new_user_notification_email` filter does not pass any `$post` object, but you're using it frequently in your code. This doesn't make any sense because the new user notification email has nothing to do with any post.

If you are creating a user when a post is published, as it appears, and then need to reference that post in the notification email, you're going to need to do it a different way, because the new user email doesn't know anything about this post.

One option would be to save the post ID as user meta `post_id` when the user is created, and then use the `$user` argument of the callback function to retrieve the value:

```
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $post_id = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'post_id', true );
    $post    = get_post( $post_id );

    // etc.
}
```

Lastly, I can see that you've also attempted to hook this function into various post status transitions:

```
add_action('new_to_pending', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email');
add_action('draft_to_pending', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email');
add_action('auto-draft_to_pending', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email');
```

I don't really know what you're doing here, but you can't use the same function as a filter on `wp_new_user_notification_email` on these hooks, because they take different arguments and do different things. If you want a function to run on these hooks, make a separate function with a different name.

Comment: Take a look at first 3 lines of his code - he’s assigning the same function for post status transition hooks also...

Comment: Millions of thanks to both for their time. I've tried before posting it in other ways, I update the post. this works with exception to the href that calls in the function because it does not bring the variable $ url of the other function.
Could you please have a look?

Comment: You should post a new question if you're experiencing a different issue. Your original question about the error has been answered.

Comment: Good! Well I restore the original question and generate the new one.https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/331232/call-to-url-in-other-function